# How to access the cardboard trigger on google Gvr( in code)?

Tags: google-cardboard, virtual-reality

How to access the cardboard trigger on google Gvr( in code) ? In the earlier version it was `Cardboard.SDK.Triggered`.  What is it in Gvr ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer .I guess its

GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onCardboardTrigger(){
        if (overlayView !== null) {
            overlayView.onTrigger();
        }
 }
```